# What is the basis to allow heart transplatation?

Tags: halacha, medicine, health-safety-shmira, resurrection-of-the-dead

If someone needs a heart transplantation, we first need to take off his old heart. At this very moment, the person is halakhically dead since he/she has no heart. A heart transplantation is therefore a kind of resurrection.

What is therefore the halakhic basis to allow the doctors to resurrect the person by heart transplantation?

Comment: The halachic concern is not resurrection, but murder (since as you say, in that time that the patient has no heart, he is like dead), but most *poskim* think that since one does this in order to lengthen the patient's life, it is not considered murder. More about this [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/assia/hashtalat-2.htm).

Comment: @Cauthon Thanks. I do not understand well hebrew, what does it say? De facto it also means resurrection is ok, no?

Comment: Well the gist of it is that most *poskim* says it's OK and is not considered murder (I guess because it's for the patient's benefit), while those that think that it may be a problem rely on the Chacham Tzvi (who emphasizes that one's life is measure by one's heartbeat, so no heart = death). But it's a lengthy discussion and I cannot say I read through it all. In addition, I didn't see anything about resurrection (I never saw a halachic refrence to resurrection), which is an interesting aspect...

Comment: Why would there be any Halakhic problem with resurrecting someone?

Comment: @Salmononius2 why not?

Comment: Note that ressurection can be considered to be allowed as we see by Elisha and the son of the SHunamese woman.  Even though it was a miracle, he did use (apparently) natural means to restart his heart.

Comment: Until I can further research the specific medical procedures involved, as I understand, some form of artificial "pump" is used in the interim, keeping the person alive on some level. Can you verify this? If true, your question has an incorrect assumption. Also, in your latest discussion, esp. w/ Salmonius2, even in modern times, we use defibrillators and CPR, etc. You could argue that the person is "dead" on some level, but they get revived constantly. I think you are making a far-fetched assumption of what halachic "death" really is. It's more complex than that!

Comment: If you hold that death really is based on heard function, wouldn't anyone who has that issue with murdering the patient also have an issue with obtaining the heart for transplant in the first place?

Comment: @sabba natural? The rishonim who were of the opinion no miracle occurred was because the kid wasnt really dead, but had just fainted. The rishonim who argued and said it was sacrilegious to say no miracle occurred said a real miracle of resurrection occurred. No one has ever said a non miraculous resurrection occurred, AFAIK at least.

Comment: @far22 "Why not?" Because there is no listed prohibition anywhere on doing so.

Comment: @far22 the only issue with resurrecting someone would be if the one performing the resurrection was a Cohen and would have to become tamei in order to  resurrect the dead person. This would only be allowed if there was pikuach nefesh involved. At least that's what Tosafos says about Eliyahu(Pinchas) resuscitating the dead boy. Reb Moshe Feinstein says bringing someone back to life is not called pikuach nefesh and is not a mitzvah so he could not have defiled himself for the child sake. He explains Tosafos' words of pikuach nefesh as referring to the kid's mother who would have died from sorrow

Answer (score 1):

Because there's no prohibition on resurrection. Source: *Sh'miras Shabas K'hilchasah* 32:20 ("מחללין את השבת כדי להפעיל אמצעי החייאה").

Answer (score -2):

there are two views on whether a person is dead according to the Torah. One of them is they die when the heart "stops working" and one of them is when the "brain stops working". The issue isn't in resurrecting the patient but in harvesting the heart from someone else. How one defines "dead" is important in terms of using someone else's organs, provided that person would be able to have an organ taken from him or her according to the Torah if they are dead.

Comment: I would think the main issue is removing the not yet broken heart from the recipient before placing in the donated heart. Is that murder?

Comment: Not likely BC it would be part if healing them which would save their life. This is even less likely so if you are taking the position of dead being in the brain